# jquery ctrlkey not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, conditional-statements

I am new to Javascript and am trying to make a function that does one thing when you shift+click a series of images (.gif) and another when you ctrl+click them. Right now I have the code set to alert when ctrl+click has occurred, however it doesn't work. My chrome console suggests that there is nothing obviously wrong with the code.

```
<script>
 $('.gif').click(function(e){

        if(e.ctrlkey) {

            alert('ctrl pressed');
        }

        if(e.shiftKey) {  

             $(this).css({
                border: 'dashed 3px black',        
             });    

            queue.push(this.id+'divless.html');

        }

        else {

            window.location.href = this.id + '.html';

        }             
    });
   </script>
```

Any help is appreciated! I have looked through ws3schools conditional statements pages as well as searched stackoverflow's related questions and cannot figure out where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsbin.com/ifavey/1/edit. Are you sure you're loading jQuery properly? Are you sure your script is loaded in dom.ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case Sensitive problem :

```
 Change e.ctrlkey by  e.ctrlKey
```

Comment: PERFECT! That has been killing me for an hour. Lowercase k looks just like uppercase K. Thanks so much!

Comment: Great! Always remember that the best thing in these cases is to go out for a walk and then review it with your eyes rested  ;)